# Magento Global Messages not displaying site wide

Tags: php, magento

I've discovered that the global messages on my magento site are no longer displaying.

Messages such as login failure, your item has been added to the cart, etc no longer display

I haven't made any changes to the templates and i've checked both the template .phtml and page.xml files to make sure that the inline code to call for the global message is there, and it is.

Oddly enough, the newsletter submission message still works

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for days now and I am still at a loss :(

Does anyone have any suggestion as to what i can do?

So as to not flood the post with code, here is my page.xml

page.xml: http://www.diegocordero.com.au/magento/page.xml

and the 3columns.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col3-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-wrapper">
                    <?php // This left_first block will display above the main content on smaller viewports ?>
                    <?php if ($_leftContent = $this->getChildHtml('left_first')): ?>
                        <div class="col-left sidebar col-left-first"><?php echo $_leftContent;   ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="col-main">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_before') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live test: www.diegocordero.com.au/magento

Comment: How should we help without seeing the code? Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks. I'm not exactly sure where to start as the only 2 areas i know where to look don't seem to be what is causing the issue. I will do what i can, thanks for bearing with me!